Kick off Azure Devops pipeline with variables from Github Actions
I have a github action yaml that builds my project in ubuntu and stores the built file in AWS s3 and an azure devops pipeline that takes that build from s3 and wraps it in a microsoft installer.
I am using the Azure Pipelines Action to kick off the Azure Devops pipeline at the end of the Github Action.
I would like to pass variables to the devops pipeline with information like the branch name and the build id so I can "version" my installer in our artifact repository. If I don't include the variables the pipeline is kicked off successfully, but if I include the variables then I get the error
   Error: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.

which seems to be an issue from the azure devops side not accepting the format of the variables. If someone has an idea of what I could be doing incorrectly it would be appreciated.
The documentation for the github action is here: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-pipelines-action.
My github action looks like this:
- name: Azure Pipelines Action
        uses: Azure/pipelines@v1.2
        with:
          azure-devops-project-url: 'https://url-to-azure-project'
          azure-pipeline-name: 'devops-pipeline' # name of the Azure pipeline to be triggered
          azure-devops-token: '${{ secrets.AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}'
          azure-pipeline-variables: '{"BRANCH_NAME": "azure-pipelines2"}'


What I missed, and is absent from the documentation is that there needs to be a corresponding user override value variable in Azure Devops pipeline. So if you want to supply a "BRANCH_NAME" variable from Github Actions, there needs to be a "BRANCH_NAME" variable in Azure Devops pipeline.

thanks for this info, facing the same issue, where did you add the varibalen name in azure devops?

@Deep When you are editing your pipeline in Azure Devops, in the upper right corner is a button called variables. You can add them there. I believe there is documentation on how to add variables through the script as well.
